# Settings page and multi edit rows

Tags: cakephp

I would like to make a configuration page like this for my CMS

http://img4.hostingpics.net/pics/72087272ok.png

I want this page (admin/settings/index) gets me the various settings (ID 1 to 21) came to my table and in case of change, I can, in this form, do an update

After 3 days of not especially fruitful research I found something. I put in my SettingsController:

```
admin_index public function () {
    if (!empty($this->data)) {
        $this->Setting->saveAll($this->request->data['Setting']);
    } else { 
    $this->request->data['Setting'] = Set::combine($this->Setting->find('all'), 
        '{n}. Setting.id', '{n}. Setting');
    }
}
```

and my view:

```
<?php
echo $this->Form->create('Setting', array ('class' => 'form-horizontal'));

foreach($this->request->data['Setting'] as $key => $value) {
    echo $this->Form->input('Setting.' . $key . '.pair');
    echo $this->Form->input('Setting.' . $key . '.id');
}

echo $this->Form->end(array('class' => 'btn btn-primary', 'label' => 'Save',
     'value' => 'Update!', 'div' => array ('class' => 'form-actions')));
?>
```

he is recovering well all my information, I can even update. The trouble is that I do not really know how I can do to get the same result as my first screenshot. He puts everything in the textarea while in some cases I want the checkbox and / or drop-down.

please help me or explain to me how to make a page that retrieves configuration information from my table and allows me to edit  without use an address like admin/settings/edit/ID

My table settings is something like this here

http://img4.hostingpics.net/pics/724403settings.png

Comment: The code in your question is badly formatted/invalid - you're asking .. how to style a form?

Comment: Why are you adding spaces everywhere in your code? It isn't readable at all! If you have debugging set to `2` in your Config/core.php you will get a lot of errors. Make sure [error_reporting](http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php) is set to `E_ALL` as well. You will notice the variable `$This` does not exist! It should be written with a lowercase 't' (`$this`). After you have validated your code and updated the question I (and I think I can speak for all the others as well) will have a look at it.

Comment: I couldn't stop thinking about `$ This` so I had to edit it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are asking about how to format the output to produce a "settings" page, you will need to do it manually or add some kind of metadata to your table schema, such as "field_type".

Now Cake will automatically generate a checkbox for a boolean or tiny int, for example, but as you have varchars, ints, texts and so on, this won't work for you (`pair` is presumably `varchar` or `text` to allow for the different possible values.

You cannot really automagically generate the outputs you want without telling Cake.

One option would be to add a `field_type` to the table, so:

```
key            value        field
site_name      My Site      input
site_online    1            checkbox
meta_desc      [some text]  textarea
```

and something like

```
foreach($settings as $setting) {
  echo $this->Form->{$setting['field']}($setting['key'], 
      array('value' => $setting['value']));
}
```

might do what you are after.

Or `if($key=='site_name') // output a textbox`

but this is not exactly ideal.

Comment: sorry for spaces it's not like that normally. I think google translate change a bit my code ^^ i'll try that thanks